# Conditional rendering with reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I want to add a div to my render objects depending on a condition. Right now I am using this code

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.test === this.someValue ? <div> some view </div> : <div> /div>}
            ...... // other components
        </div>
    )
}
```

this is working but I don't like the `: <div> /div>` because I don't need it. Is there any way to just use an `if` instead of `if else`?

Comment: you can return a `null` instead of an empty `div` as well

Comment: I would rather suggest you to go for the `recompose's branch`. Have a look at it here : https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#branch

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use only the first condition and return your desired component right away since JavaScript has [short-circuit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) evaluation.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
     {this.test === this.someValue && <div> some view </div>}
     ......
    </div> 
  )
}
```

Comment: Here is a link to the react docs that outline all the conditional rendering schemes. https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning an `empty div` just because you have to have a second condition, you could return `null` instead like

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.test === this.someValue ? <div> some view </div> : null}
            ...... // other components
        </div>
    )
}
```